# Installing Ubuntu over windows and existing partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu,becouse i am sick of windows.I have partition with windows7(c:),partition wih some private data(d) and some programs/games(e). I don't want to have no windows,no private data and no games,justo state like this in meaning of partitions :c,d,e - all blank except c(ubuntu on it)- and d: and e: ready for Ubuntu to handle it and save stuff on it.How to do this? If i choose install over win7,will this erase not only data but partitions too? and if to choose alone to handle installation and partitioning,what to do to have state like i have (c:d: and e:)? Partition sizes are : c-488 GB,D - 976 GB,E-398 GB,justo to say - ram 8GB(i supose don't need extra swap creation.)
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During install Ubuntu will ask you how you want it to be installed.
You can choose to install it in an existing partition, leaving the other partitions untouched.
You can choose to let ubuntu take the whole disk.
Or you can choose to do it manually which is not really difficult.

You can always cancel the install at this point if you change your mind and nothing will be changed.

But beware:
After you made your decisions and commit the changes they will be
written to disk.
But Ubuntu will warn you when this is about to happen so don't worry.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Woow.That is one fast answer :) Thanks for that. If option where "Ubuntu will install in existing partition" is selected,Ubuntu will recognize those partitions?

Comment: yes, ubuntu will recognize all partitions :-)

Comment: Oh, and when you regard your question as solved, don't hesitate to mark it as such ;-)